# How reliable is it to pick an array position with math floor and random?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Maybe this question is a little stupid but... is this code 100% reliable?

```
var fortunes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
var pick = fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)];
```

Let me explain my point. If I understand it correctly, `Math.random()` returns a number from 0 to 1, both included. So, it is very unprovable but it is possible that it returns 1. Therefore, in the following code, we would be selecting the 8th element (that doesn't exist) as `Math.floor( 1 * 7 ) = 7`  ( `fortunes[7]` doesn't exist).

Comment: Math.random give a number from 0 inclusive to 1 _exclusive_ [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***If*** `Math.random` did return a value in the range [0, 1] (that is, 1 inclusive), your code would *not* be reliable. However rarely a `1` might be returned, the case would exist and would eventually lead to an error.

However, `Math.random` returns a value in the range [0, 1), that is **excluding 1**. So your code is safe.

Comment: @Vandervals no, it's not the case. *EVER*. That's the point! Read his last line.

Comment: If 1 *could* be returned, simply test for it and if occurs, get another random number: `do {var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)} while(n==1)`. ;-) Since it occurs **very** rarely, it won't be an issue.

Comment: @deceze—that's not trying random things, it's a precise solution for an extremely rare event. It has an even chance of occurring once in about 31,700 years if one random number is generated every millisecond.

Comment: @RobG Still, you're repeatedly doing a random action until the action randomly matches your expectation. However rarely it might *not* match your expectation, there's still a (tiny tiny practically negligible) chance that you *may* be repeating the action indefinitely.

Comment: There is a vanishingly small chance that it will happen more than once in a century of continuous running and absolutely zero chance of it occurring indefinitely, ever.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is correct.
As per MDN Docs[[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)], The range of Math.random() is `[0, 1)` meaning including-0-until-but-not-including-1.

So do what you're doing.

Comment: thanks! Just curious, is this true in other languages as well?

Comment: That depends on the language you're using. I can't vouch for all of them :P Although I'm inclined to assume that other languages *may* follow the same pattern. Again, check before writing code.

Comment: if you ever come across a language that's 0-1 INCLUSIVE, multiply by 0.9999999 (this figure is arbitrary, but a optimal value can be be determined mathematically based on the range of output required) - you could also `Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length) % fortunes.length` - but that would give 0 twice as much probability as other numbers